# Looping through the list python aws

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am new to python and trying to figure this out for long.

```
a ='''arn:aws:elastic:us-west-1:111111111111:loadbalancer/app/**abc**/888888888888888
arn:aws:elastic:us-west-1:111111111111:loadbalancer/app/def/888888888888888
arn:aws:elastic:us-west-1:111111111111:loadbalancer/app/ghi/888888888888888
arn:aws:elastic:us-west-1:111111111111:loadbalancer/app/test/888888888888888'''

print(a)
```

How to loop through the only string

```
'arn:aws:elastic:us-west-:111111111111:loadbalancer/app/**abc**/888888888888888'
```

from the list without specifying in the code even if it's position changes?
Please explain! Thank you!

Comment: Which string? Everything is string in your example?

Comment: This should the output everytime even if the position changes - 'arn:aws:elastic:us-west-:111111111111:loadbalancer/app/**abc**/888888888888888'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split a string with the methode `split`

```
a ='''arn:aws:elastic:us-west-1:111111111111:loadbalancer/app/**abc**/888888888888888
arn:aws:elastic:us-west-1:111111111111:loadbalancer/app/def/888888888888888
arn:aws:elastic:us-west-1:111111111111:loadbalancer/app/ghi/888888888888888
arn:aws:elastic:us-west-1:111111111111:loadbalancer/app/test/888888888888888'''
for i, split_txt in enumerate(a.split()):
    print(f'{i+1}. string: {split_txt}')
```

Output

```
1. string: arn:aws:elastic:us-west-1:111111111111:loadbalancer/app/**abc**/888888888888888
2. string: arn:aws:elastic:us-west-1:111111111111:loadbalancer/app/def/888888888888888
3. string: arn:aws:elastic:us-west-1:111111111111:loadbalancer/app/ghi/888888888888888
4. string: arn:aws:elastic:us-west-1:111111111111:loadbalancer/app/test/888888888888888
```

If you only want the first line

```
a.split()[0]
'arn:aws:elastic:us-west-1:111111111111:loadbalancer/app/**abc**/888888888888888'
```

If you want to find the line with different pattern

```
for i in a.split():
    if '**abc**' in i:
        print(i)
arn:aws:elastic:us-west-1:111111111111:loadbalancer/app/**abc**/888888888888888
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should do the trick:

```
for line in a.split():
    print(line)
```

And if you want to find the line you mentioned:

```
for line in a.split():
    if line == 'arn:aws:elastic:us-west-:111111111111:loadbalancer/app/**abc**/888888888888888':
        print(line)
```